# What's the IPTABLES query to allow 9987 UDP in?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to configure my VPS so it'll host a teamspeak server, but I've hit a snag with correctly configuring iptables to allow connections in. I attempted to do it myself, but I ended up allowing TCP in instead of UDP. How do I go about deleting this and/or inputting in an allow UDP on 9987 rule?

'ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9987'

Answer (score 8):

> iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT

`-A` means "Append to the end of the named chain" `-p` means "what protocol?" `--dport` lets you specify port and `-j` means "jump to this chain."

Comment: -A actually means "Append" to the end of the named chain. Conversely, -I means "Insert" to the top of the chain.